# Issue with Menu.Item NavLink always active Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic ui react and I am using NavLink with Menu.Item for routing.

Below is my navbar component:

```
const Navbar = () => (
  <div>
    <Container>
      <Menu secondary stackable widths={4}>
        <Menu.Item>
          <img src={Logo} alt="header" />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as={NavLink} to="/" name="home">
          <Icon name="home" size="large" />
          <p>Home</p>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as={NavLink} to="/data" name="data">
          <Icon name="dashboard" size="large" />
          <p>Dashboard</p>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item as={NavLink} to="/user" name="user">
          <Icon name="user" size="large" />
          <p>User</p>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    </Container>
  </div>
);
```

Now here is where the issue resides. The routing works fine but for some reason the 'Home' Menu Item is **always active**.

However the other two routes work fine (i.e. are only set 'active' when route is correct)

[Here is what it looks like with /dashboard route active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcnVK.png)

The code for the routes in my App.jsx:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/data" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/user" component={User} />
</Switch>
```

The photo above should give you a clear indication of the issue!

Any input would be appreciated!!

Comment: <Menu.Item as={NavLink} exact to="/" name="home"> add `exact` prop to your Menu Item

Comment: @AngelSalazar Thanks my friend just ran into this behavior! And you solved it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can confirm as from AngelSalazar above, this fixes it. Thank you!

```
<Menu.Item as={NavLink} exact to="/" name="home">
```

Comment: It's only working for me if the Navigation component has state set in MapStateToProps, that shouldn't be the case right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the setup that I have that helped fix the issue.
I was getting the following error:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
in a (created by Link)
in Link (created by Route)
in Route (created by NavLink)
in NavLink (created by MenuItem)
in MenuItem (at NavBar.js:47)
in a (created by Link)
in Link (created by Route)
in Route (created by NavLink)
in NavLink (at NavBar.js:46)
in div (created by Menu)
in Menu (at NavBar.js:20)
in NavBar (at App.js:26)
in div (at App.js:25)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at App.js:24)
in div (at App.js:22)
in App (at index.js:6)
```

The main component setup was in App.js where I was doing my routing

```
 <Router>
      <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Route exact path="/" component={LoginSignUpContainer}></Route>
<Router>
```

Here I have my NavBar component which holds the  and  where I was having the issue.

```
class NavBar extends Component{
 constructor(){
    super();

    this.state={
        activeItem: "home"
    }
}
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })


render() {
const { activeItem } = this.state

return (
  <Menu>
     <NavLink to="/bills">
    <Menu.Item
      name='bills'
      active={activeItem === 'bills'}
      onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
      <Icon name="payment"/>Bills
    </Menu.Item>

  <Menu>
```

I removed the NavLink tags and within the Menu.Item tags I added:

```
 as={NavLink}
 to="bills"
```

After update:

```
<Menu.Item
    as={NavLink}
    to="/bills"
    name='bills'
    active={activeItem === 'bills'}
    onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
  <Icon name="payment"/>Login
</Menu.Item>
```